# How to concisely check if tuples have no overlappping members

Tags: scala, tuples

I have two `Tuple2[String, String]` and I want to check if they have no overlapping coordinates. Here is an example:

```
def checkOverlapping(t1: (String, String), t2: (String, String)) =
  t1._1 == t2._1 || t1._1 == t2._2 || t1._2 == t2._1 || t1._2 == t2._2
```

It works, but looks extremely ugly. In case of `Tuple4[String, String, String, String]` it seems crazy to manually check all of the collision by hand.

Is there a concise way that would work for `TupleX` of `String`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def checkOverlapping(x: Product, y: Product): Boolean = {
  val s = x.productIterator.toSet
  y.productIterator.exists(s)
}
```

This works on tuples of arbitrary arity, also if the arity is different and the types aren't `String` but something else. Actually, it works on all kinds of things, including `case`-classes. The type safety basically goes out of the window, but yes - it is concise. If you need it only for specific types of tuples, then replacing `Product` by the type of those tuples would be a simple way of regaining the type safety.